# Telegram retry send method

Tags: android, telegram, send

We can see in telegram that when we are offline and we want to send a message or file , the message or file are waiting for internet and when internet is accessible they will send , how can i add this ability to my app?

Comment: check internet connection is there or not in that make this retry condition

Comment: How can i save file or message in cache?

Comment: make a session for that

Comment: I am a beginner , Can you redirect me to an usefull code or page about that?

Comment: use this library : implementation 'com.treebo:internetavailabilitychecker:1.0.1'

Comment: i can check internet connection and network state changes but i need to something like queue for saving actions and when user will be online this queue start synchronize with database until user will be offline again